# Ruby UDFs in PIG script

Tags: ruby, hadoop, rubygems

I'm using Ruby User Defined Function (UDF) in the Pig scripts. Now the requirement is to use "bunny" gem in the UDF so I installed that gem on all the data nodes. But when I'm accessing that gem in the Pig UDF it is not available there. From local script, I can use that gem on each machine but via Pig script it is not accessible.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I got the problem. Pig uses Jython and JRuby libraries for compiling python and ruby udfs. So it doesn't make any difference if we install additional module in the slave nodes separately. The preferable way is to use pig streaming features in these kind of scenarios.